# accordion toggle not change icon in bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code for multiple/dynamic accordion toggle using bootstrap 3 and jQuery:

```
$('div.accordion-body').on('shown', function () {
    $(this).parent("div").find(".fa").removeClass("fa fa fa-plus").addClass("fa fa-minus");

});

$('div.accordion-body').on('hidden', function () {
    $(this).parent("div").find(".fa").removeClass("fa fa-minus").addClass("fa fa fa-plus");
});
```

But in bootstrap 3 change icon(`fa-plus` to `fa-minus`) not work. How do fix this ?!

Bootstrap 3 [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BVmUL/1619/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beacuse in Bootstrap 3 the `events` `shown` and `hidden` have been changed to `show.bs.collapse` and `hide.bs.collapse`:

```
$('div.accordion-body').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $(this).parent("div").find(".fa").removeClass("fa fa fa-plus").addClass("fa fa-minus");

});

$('div.accordion-body').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
    $(this).parent("div").find(".fa").removeClass("fa fa-minus").addClass("fa fa fa-plus");
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/BVmUL/1620/)

Answer (score 0):

The event names have changed since 2.x. See the new events here http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-events

```
$('div.accordion-body').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
    $(this).parent("div").find(".fa").removeClass("fa fa fa-plus").addClass("fa fa-minus");
});

$('div.accordion-body').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
    $(this).parent("div").find(".fa").removeClass("fa fa-minus").addClass("fa fa fa-plus");
});
```